# php find out if array contains values of over 0?

Tags: php, arrays

Without looping through each value in an array, is there any shortcut to checking whether it contains values over 0?

Eg

`array(3,0,0)` would be TRUE

`array(0,0,0)` would be FALSE

`array(-2,0,-3)` would be FALSE

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if (max(array(3,0,0)) > 0) echo 'greater than 0';
```

Comment: I am uncertain if this qualifies as a true shortcut. It may be shorter to type in code, but the implementation cannot be more efficient than a loop.

Comment: @Feysal are we talking about premature micro optimization? If yes: don't do it...