# Check if an array has different value than zero

Tags: php

I need to check if in my array there are values different than 0 (for this particular case). Also the array may vary from 1 element to `m` elements. More or less something like the inverse of [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

My array is of the form: (these are random numbers, that can change position)

```
 array('0', '1', '1', '3', '1', '5', '0' '2' /*...*/);
```

Is there such function, or do I need to do a loop to run the whole array and check each index?

Comment: Do you need to return those values, or do you know need to check there exists values other than 0?

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266757/php-find-out-if-array-contains-values-of-over-0

Comment: Just check. Exactly something like that question that I was looking for, but could not find it. Thanks for the answers, will use the max(), didn't even think of that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `max()` which returns the highest value from the array

```
    if (max($myArray) > 0) { #do ur thing }
```

Comment: I'd rather use `if (max($myArray))` which would include the case with negative numbers in array.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the input array contains only negative values and zeros, then the `max()` will be 0 and this will be a false-positive conditional evaluation.  If negative numbers are not possible, then I agree with skobaljic that `max($myArray)` will do.  This caveat may not pertain to the OP's question, but it may be pertinent to researchers.

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it, here is one:

```
function has_other_than_zero( $array ) {
    return intval(implode($array, ''));
}
```

Comment: When gluing with an empty string, `implode()` doesn't need the glue parameter to be declared (it is the default).  There may be some instances where this falls down: https://3v4l.org/sOXRf